# proftpd on VPS - No such user found

Tags: plesk, proftpd

I'm running a brand new installed VPS with CentOS 6.6 and Plesk 12.0.18. I created a subscription and by default a FTP user is created. However, I cannot login with these credentials. I also created a new user but the same problem presists. I'm 100% sure that the username and password is correct.

Filezilla gives me and `530 Login incorrect`. But if I look at the `/var/log/secure` file, I see this odd message (FTP username = `test`):

```
Jan 30 16:01:45 transip proftpd: PAM unable to dlopen(/lib64/security/pam_stack.so): /lib64/security/pam_stack.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Jan 30 16:01:45 transip proftpd: PAM adding faulty module: /lib64/security/pam_stack.so
Jan 30 16:01:45 transip proftpd: pam_listfile(proftpd:auth): Couldn't open /etc/ftpusers
Jan 30 16:01:45 transip proftpd[18085]: 127.0.0.1 (x.x.x.x[x.x.x.x]) - USER test (Login failed): No such user found
```

`No such user found`, although it is created with Plesk. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try to test login when SELinux is off: # setenforce 0

Comment: That indeed works! No I have to disable it permenantly. But I don't know the downsize of that, need to look at that!

Comment: Here the article how to disable SELinux http://kb.sp.parallels.com/115626

Comment: Could you please share content of /etc/pam.d/proftpd ?

Comment: @Every-one-in-the-universe, why do you keep telling people to disable SELinux? This is not the solution, this is a workaround